# Can we close syntax errors in PHP as duplicate

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

Recently i go through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them) and found it explaining mostly all types of **syntax errors**(Except function syntax error).

So when we come across posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926734/html-tag-causing-unexpected-end-of-file-in-php-file) question and other errors covered in the first link , can we mark it as duplicate of first link ?

Comment: not clear what you are asking especially since both links are to the same post

Comment: @charlietfl see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926734/html-tag-causing-unexpected-end-of-file-in-php-file) question. can we close these type of questions as duplicate

Comment: You can mark it as a duplicate, you'd just have to get enough people to agree with you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thats why i brought it here,to check whether others were thinking like same and could link this post if the flag has been rejected

Comment: I posted the last close vote as there is a reason to close - there was a typo. Is it a duplicate of the Syntax Errors post? Depends on your point of view.